# How to get a count of first elements and sum of second element in a list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, collections, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples and I am expecting a dictionary where I want to count number of times the first element is repeated and sum of all the second elements.

For eg :-

```
input_list = [('Skills', 3), ('Wholesome', 3), ('FanArt', 3), ('Clip', 3), ('Skills', 2), ('FanArt', 2)]
```

Expected Output :

```
{"Skills": 5, "Wholesome": 3, "FanArt": 5, "Clip": 3}
```

I am expecting a optimised way to do this

I have tried it with simple programming with for loops. But I want to use itertools or some built in package.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Where in the expected output is the desired "count of first elements"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
input_list = [('Skills', 3), ('Wholesome', 3), ('FanArt', 3), ('Clip', 3), ('Skills', 2), ('FanArt', 2)]


output_dict = {}
# Looping over tuple value
for k, v in input_list:
    if (k in output_dict): # if key exists then add value
        output_dict[k] += v
    else:
        output_dict[k] = v # if key not exists then key:value
print(output_dict)
```

---

You can also use the default list

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list = [('Skills', 3), ('Wholesome', 3), ('FanArt', 3), ('Clip', 3), ('Skills', 2), ('FanArt', 2)]
output_dict = defaultdict(int)


for key, value in input_list:
    output_dict[key] += value

print(dict(output_dict))
```

---

`Counter` from collections will also work same as above

```
from collections import Counter

input_list = [('Skills', 3), ('Wholesome', 3), ('FanArt', 3), ('Clip', 3), ('Skills', 2), ('FanArt', 2)]

output_dict = Counter()

for key, value in input_list:
    output_dict[key] += value

print(dict(output_dict))
```

Output

```
{'Skills': 5, 'Wholesome': 3, 'FanArt': 5, 'Clip': 3} # for all above code
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a sorted list:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

input_list = [
    ("Skills", 3),
    ("Wholesome", 3),
    ("FanArt", 3),
    ("Clip", 3),
    ("Skills", 2),
    ("FanArt", 2),
]

# Sort the input list by the first element of each tuple
sorted_list = sorted(input_list, key=itemgetter(0))

# you can also use a lambda function as a key
# sorted_list = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x: x[0])

# Use groupby to group the tuples by the first element
grouped_data = groupby(sorted_list, key=itemgetter(0))

# Create a dictionary with the sums of the second elements for each group
result = {key: sum(item[1] for item in group) for key, group in grouped_data}
```

---

Using reduce from functools:

```py
result = reduce(lambda acc, t: {**acc, tup[0]: acc.get(tup[0], 0) + tup[1]}, input_list, {})
```

`**acc` gets the key/values pairs from acc(same as **kwargs).

Comment: Sorting the list gives O(N log N) time complexity, whereas the simple for-loop approaches are O(N). So this works but it isn't an optimisation.